# Why json format can't has the same ID value of different object?

Tags: json, formatting

I'm having problem when I set the same id value of different object's attribute like below : `"timestampId":4,"UserId":4,"ParentId":4,`

[image]

**but when i change to different value, It works properly :**

[image]

Comment: Since your question is really about unexpected server behavior, you will need to provide more information about the `eHealthBackend` server code in order for anyone to be able to help answer your question.

Answer (score 9):

JSON itself **can** have the same value in different attributes — there is nothing wrong with it.

It is your API endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/eHealthBackend/NewUserAccountParent`) that does not accept the same value for certain attributes. Apparently it has some validation logic doing that, for example a user's `parentId` cannot be the same as `userId` which kind of makes sense — you cannot be parent to yourself.

Comment: Hi @DrakeES, thank for your answer. 
I'm not sure about validation logic doing that or not.
My project is generated by scaffolding on myEclipse and I couldn't  find where those validations are implemented in my project.

Comment: Those validations would be in the backend code (`eHealthBackend`).

Answer (score 1):

I think @DrakeES is right,there might be some validation in Your API,as per the data, when you check the working example image which you have put here,you can see that you are sending the **PARENTID:6**, but you are getting **PARENTID:2** as response.